# How do you copy a SAS file share that has more than 256 character

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, windows-server-2016, sas

Is it possible to copy a SAS file share that the path has more than 256 character within Win 10 or Win Server?  And if not, what options do I have?

Comment: In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. But we could refe to the link to change the size. https://lifehacker.com/windows-10-allows-file-names-longer-than-260-characters-1785201032 and use command line to copy "robocopy /E source destination"

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API normally imposes a [maximum length for a path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) ('MAX_PATH') of 260 characters. To specify a path of unusual size, which must be an absolute path and cannot be a relative path, use a prefix of two backstroke characters, a question mark, and another backstroke character preceding the path, e.g., "\\?\" (omit the quotation marks, please). For example,

\\?\D:\path_of_unusual_size